# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Is it possible to create a Challenge Handler in native class instead of JavaScript?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

We are writing a Hybrid application mixed with Native pages in worklight 6.1 for `ios`.

We are now implementing security features on adapter-side and I have read the documentation for it from [Adapter Based Authentication](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_22_-_Adapter_Based_Authentication.pdf).

My problem is that our login module is implemented in a fully native page and I would like to also implement the challenge handler over there. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You can write challenge handlers in native by following the Worklight iOS native APIs (http://ibm.co/1fDoDJh - see page 28 "ChallengeHandler").

One important thing to note is that at the time of this writing, if you plan to share a session between native and hybrid code, you MUST start the server session from the Hybrid side (and not the native side). You could for example use connectOnStartup or manually connect in javascript before you display your native pages.

In future versions this should work both ways...

Comment: I din't get you, if app is getting login from native page then how would i start session from javascript because userid , password and other information whatever required for correct session is available in login module. Can you please elaborate what need to be done in this case.

Comment: You say your application is a Hybrid application; this means that the Worklight framework first initializes, so you can set connectOnStartup:true in initOptions.js to connect to the Worklight Server. This means you get all the data you need and so when you do wl.nativepage.show to go to the native page to do your login, it will use the same session. I believe this is what Nathan means.

Comment: Right, when I say "session" it doesn't mean the user needs to be already logged-in. It just means the device needs to connect at least once with the server to receive a session ID.

Comment: Just let me know what happen when i do connectOnStartup false in my app , if i am not using direct update from server and is there any docs where i can go through all the process happening ducring connectOnStartup true.

Comment: With connectOnStartup:false the Worklight framework initializes w/out first connecting to the Worklight Server. With connectOnStartup:true the Worklight framework initializes and also invokes WL.Client.connect(); You can search and read about WL.Client.connect at the IBM Worklight Information Center: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp

Comment: @NathanH Could you please let me know the status of this feature? Shall i need to update 6.2?

Comment: Yes @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy 6.2 shares native/hybrid sessions very well!