# IBM Worklight - How to hide the HTML page in a Hybrid app and load native page instead?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am developing a hybrid app and my first page is native page in both `android` and `ios`. I kept initial html page as blank white background and loading native page by using the `WL.nativePage.show` API method.

I am able to go to native page but after the splash screen, it's showing a white screen which is my HTML page for a while then the native pages is displayed. So I want to avoid that white screen. How to do that?

My code for showing native is:

```
function wlCommonInit() {
     WL.NativePage.show('ProductHomeViewController', backFromNativePage, params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not easily doable in Worklight 6.1, but is likely to be improved in a later release.

- In Android, you can change in `AndroidManifest.xml` the default `activity` the application starts with that of yours (the activity you have created for your Native Page)
- In iOS, you can start another `UIViewController` from `CDVMainViewController`

The above will help to have a Hybrid app that its "start page" (the page you see after the splash image) is a native page, HOWEVER, this will not help in sharing the session between the Hybrid and Native pages ([as explained in the answer to this question by you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757179/ibm-worklight-6-1-is-it-possible-to-create-a-challenge-handler-in-native-class)).

There is work in progress to create a Cordova plug-in that will allow session sharing between hybrid and native pages when the native page is the starting page of the application; it is not yet ready. As I wrote at the top, in a future release all of this should work better.

---

To address the questions in the comments:

The Hybrid application also contains that same Native API as a Native application would, this means that once you launch the app and navigate to a native page after the splash image (based on the above), you can still use the same native API methods to connect to the Worklight Server, invoke Worklight Adapters, etc.

The problem is still the sharing of the cookies (session) between the native webview and the hybrid webview.

Again, as written above, there is work in progress to create a Cordova plug-in that will allow session sharing between hybrid and native pages when the native page is the starting page of the application; it is not yet ready. In a future release all of this should work better.

Comment: I understood this , but let me know if i am loading native page first instead of main html file how would i call adapter from my native page    do i need to initialise WL framework to do adapter call in native because i am not loading html page at start and am not able to call adapter if i do that.

Comment: @vishal_g, tomorrow I will revise my answer and try to reply to these additional questions.

Comment: @vishal_g, if this answer helped you resolve your problem, please mark it as Answered.